# This long sentence is ambiguous, and difficult for me to understand

Tags: meaning, ambiguity, legalese, syntactic-analysis

I got this sentence

> Property value litigation is no different than any other type of litigation where experts are used in that expert opinions are fair game for attack by the opposing side in discovery and certainly at trial.

from [this](http://www.americanbar.org/groups/litigation/committees/realestate/news_analysis/articles_2013/042011-expert-witness-positional-bias.html) website.

I can understand this sentence in two ways:

1. We have experts' opinions, and then the opposing side attack experts' opinions.
2. The opposing side has an opinion, and then we use experts' opinions to challenge it.

Which one is more reasonable? I think it's more likely to be the first one.

Thanks.

Comment: Your sentence says nothing about *using experts' opinions to challenge [the opposing side's opinion]* as per your point #2. All it says is that in *those types of litigation where experts are used*, both sides consider it "fair game" to attack any expert opinions presented by the other side. Exactly *how* each opposing side does this isn't specified, so you have nothing on which to base interpretation #2.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about logic, not language

Comment: No, it's really about commas. The author seems to have taken a vow never to use them. That's the equivalent of reading every syllable at the same tone and volume and rate forever and ever alleluia alleluia. It should be _Property value litigation is no different than any other type of litigation where experts are used, in that expert opinions are fair game for attack by the opposing side in discovery, and certainly at trial._

Answer (score 1):

It is about language. Since the author was careful not to specify one side or the other (only saying "the opposing side"), I would construe it symmetrically, to mean  #1, AND  "The opposing side presents experts' opinions, and we attack them." (both of these occurring often in discovery and always at trial.)  I do not glean #2 from it though.